# fixed width and height of svg objects

Tags: object, svg, fixed-width

I want to keep my polygon circle and path width same width and height on all devices for example 50px height and 50px width, because they are streched on mobile devices, or if there is another solution.
i deleted some css classes and other svg objects so code can be seen as simple.

```
    <svg preserveAspectRatio="none" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 734 414">
<g id="bg">
        <rect class="cls-1" x="-0.01" y="0.96" width="733.99" height="92.47" />
        <g id="bg_elements">
            <path class="cls-2" d="M734,414H0V81.84s56,2.53,74.56,2.73c22,.23,64.67-3,86.71-2.86,24.83.18,109.22,6.38,136.17,7.46,45.2,1.8,105-5.57,149.73-7.27,39.45-1.51,118.14,3.66,157.5,3.66,32.42,0,129.33-5.29,129.33-5.29Z" />
            <g id="elements">
                <polygon id="triangle" class="cls-3" points="32.27 247.14 23.13 224.36 7.97 243.67 32.27 247.14" />
                <circle id="ellipse" class="cls-4" cx="317.06" cy="160.33" r="12.53" />
                <polygon id="triangle_s" class="cls-5" points="460.08 371.37 448.65 376.05 438.89 383.61 440.56 371.37 438.89 359.14 448.65 366.7 460.08 371.37" />
                <path id="plus" class="cls-6" d="M651.11,227l-13.62,21.69m-4- 
   17.66,21.7,13.63" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: If I understand you you need a square undistorted svg element. In this case you need to remove `preserveAspectRatio="none"` and change the viewBox attribute so that the width is the same as the height, for example `viewBox="0 0 734 734"`

Comment: this svg is used as background cover, so iz need to be streched full width and height and elements should be moved over that area, so i need to be fully covered viewport with fixed width and height of these elements

Comment: You can't have no stretching and fully covering of an area that has a variable aspect ratio. Something's got to give.

Answer (score 1):

If the svg has the `viewBox` and `preserveAspectRatio` all set, another place possibility is to use a container div and `font-size` something like:

```
        <div style="height: 50px; width: 50px; fontSize: 50px">
           <svg>...</svg>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are not clear.  But perhaps what you want, is for the SVG to cover the whole of the viewport whilst still staying unstretched/unsquashed.  Ie. the equivalent of `background-size: cover` for HTML elements.

If that is the case, then what you want is:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
```

This will size the SVG up or down so that it is the minimum size that still entirely covers the whole of the viewport.  However you may end up with some parts of the SVG getting clipped off the edges.

```css
svg {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
}

path {
  fill: red;
}

circle {
  fill: blue;
}

polygon {
  fill: yellow;
}
```

```html
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" viewBox="0 0 734 414">
<g id="bg">
        <rect class="cls-1" x="-0.01" y="0.96" width="733.99" height="92.47" />
        <g id="bg_elements">
            <path class="cls-2" d="M734,414H0V81.84s56,2.53,74.56,2.73c22,.23,64.67-3,86.71-2.86,24.83.18,109.22,6.38,136.17,7.46,45.2,1.8,105-5.57,149.73-7.27,39.45-1.51,118.14,3.66,157.5,3.66,32.42,0,129.33-5.29,129.33-5.29Z" />
            <g id="elements">
                <polygon id="triangle" class="cls-3" points="32.27 247.14 23.13 224.36 7.97 243.67 32.27 247.14" />
                <circle id="ellipse" class="cls-4" cx="317.06" cy="160.33" r="12.53" />
                <polygon id="triangle_s" class="cls-5" points="460.08 371.37 448.65 376.05 438.89 383.61 440.56 371.37 438.89 359.14 448.65 366.7 460.08 371.37" />
                <path id="plus" class="cls-6" d="M651.11,227l-13.62,21.69m-4- 
   17.66,21.7,13.63" />
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```